# Excel Hyperlinks stop working intermittently

Tags: excel, hyperlink

Currently working in an Excel 2010 spreadheet containing macros and also hyperlinks to other cells/tabs within the same document (a contents page linking to other sheets).

The hyperlinks work without any issues for a short time (perhaps a day or two) but upon re-opening the file the hyperlinks will no longer work. Hovering over the cell containing the hyperlink gives you a screen tip containing the file path and file name but appears to have lost the sheet and cell reference.

Has anyone else encountered this and found a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: I want to help you; but, unfortunately, this question has no answer. it needs to be researched

Comment: Hi pnuts, I'm not being pedantic, but how long is a long file name? I'm saving the file to a network, rather than locally on my machine. Thanks

Comment: Hi Andrew. Sorry, do you mean I need to work the answer out for myself or that you don't know of any available solution at the moment?